# (To file an emacs bug report) are there services out there that let's me ssh to a clean GNU Linux machine

Tags: linux

I want to file a bug report about emacs.

From what I learnt, bug reports relating to GNU/Linux
are given precedence over more exotic OS's like MacOS.

I can spin up an ubuntu instance in 10 seconds using my (free)
Amazon AWS cloud login. But ubuntu is not "sanctioned"
at https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html

Is there a quick way to ssh to a "fresh" GNU Linux instance
for the purpose of demo'ing a possible bug.

sidenote1: There used to be a free service called sdf.org, I believe they have
tightened up their signup requirements, and I'm not sure what OS they have

sidenote2: virtualbox slows down my Mac to a crawl, plus my SSD is almost full.

Comment: If you make it too cumbersome for the developers to duplicate the bug's behavior, you might as well consider the bug as remaining open indefinitely (in my opinion, that is) ....

Comment: Where did you hear that GNU/Linux is given precedence? AFAIK, that's not true.

Comment: I think you'd be fine just using Ubuntu. You'll note that the FSF's list of free distros is missing just about every popular disro that people actually use because they are not fully compliant with the FSF's free software guidelines. However, I doubt that they're disregard a report from those distros. If they did, they'd have to ignore just about every but report they get...

Comment: > Where did you hear that. here. 
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-02/msg00524.html

Comment: RMS/FSF/GNU can make whatever policies they like, but what actually determines which bugs are given precedence are the volunteers answering them (of which there are currently somewhat less macOS users, I think, but the policy doesn't directly dictate that).

Comment: sdf.org runs NetBSD, according to http://sdf.org/?faq?BASICS?01

Comment: I haven't tried this: https://github.com/revmischa/heroku-emacs but I remember that Heroku used to give you a fee (albeit very limited) account. You could try that.

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior you've taken that message out of context. If you submit a clear, reproducible, bug report, then there's no reason to expect it will get less attention just because you're not using GNU/Linux. The only exception might be if it's an issue that *only* effects MacOS - that would only be a problem because fewer of the developers (i.e., just the ones with Macs) will be able to work with it.